# Swift 4 Alert with Input

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create an alert with two input fields which contain a master password for this app. It's my first app. I saw a function online and wanted to see if it still works but it doesn't seem to pop up with the alert when the function is called. Has this been changed in Swift 4?

```
func showInputDialog() {
    //Creating UIAlertController and
    //Setting title and message for the alert dialog
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Master Password", message: "Enter your Master and confirm it!", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //the confirm action taking the inputs
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default) { (_) in

        //getting the input values from user
        let master = alertController.textFields?[0].text
        let confirm = alertController.textFields?[1].text

        if master == confirm {
            self.labelCorrect.isHidden = true
            self.labelCorrect.text = master
        }

    }

    //the cancel action doing nothing
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    //adding textfields to our dialog box
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Master"
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Confirm Password"
    }

    //adding the action to dialogbox
    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //finally presenting the dialog box
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This code works fine for me in Swift 4, I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't work for me. Did you call it on the view load or on a button press?

Comment: Btw when posting a question post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: you can't present an alert controller on viewDidLoad. You need to override viewDidAppear `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated) showInputDialog() }` and call `showInputDialog()` from there, if you call it inside viewDidLoad you should get **Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy**

Comment: @RyanNacker, I tested call of this func in viewDidAppear, and on button press. As Leo Dabus already mentioned above you can't present view controllers in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I got it working by using the view did appear method. I wasn’t getting an error so there was no error to post. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 5):

```
    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Description", preferredStyle: .alert)


    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "User"
    }

    alert.addTextField { (textFieldPass) in
        textFieldPass.placeholder = "Password"
        textFieldPass.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    // 3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        print("cerrar")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert?.textFields![0]
        let textFieldPass = alert?.textFields![1]
        print("Text field: \(textField!.text)")
        print("Text field: \(textFieldPass!.text)")
        self.Autentificacion(usuario: textField!.text!, clave: textFieldPass!.text!)
    }))
    // 4. Present the alert.
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Going off as a reference to your question and daniel fernando muñoz melendez answer, I have written some code below.

```
        //Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login", message: "For User", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextField { (userField) in
        userField.placeholder = "User"
    }

    alert.addTextField { (passWordField) in
        passWordField.placeholder = "Password"
        passWordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    //the cancel action doing nothing
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive)

    //the confirm action taking the inputs
    let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        guard let userField = alert?.textFields?[0], let passWordField = alert?.textFields?[1] else {
            print("Issue with Alert TextFields")
            return
        }
        guard let userName = userField.text, let passWord = passWordField.text else {
            print("Issue with TextFields Text")
            return
        }
        print("Text field: \(userName)")
        print("Text field: \(passWord)")

        // Condition Logic
    })

    //adding the actions to alertController
    alert.addAction(acceptAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Presenting the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The guard statement for the alert.textFields act as a check to make sure the text fields are in fact created and are not nil.
The guard statement for the userField.text is to make sure that the text in them can be cast to a String. It should be noted that even if the user does not enter anything into the text fields it will still run properly. Since you want them to enter in credentials, I would assume you don't want this to happen and recommend putting your condition logic there. Or have it like daniel fernando muñoz melendez did it and have it in a separate function.
Let me know if you need any clarification.